# angular 2 observable json error

Tags: json, angular

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http,Response } from '@angular/http';
import {Observable} from 'rxjs/Observable';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/catch';
import 'rxjs/add/observable/throw';


@Injectable()
export class CommentService{
private _url :string ="https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts"
   constructor(private _http:Http){}
  // method to fetch CommentS from a api service 
 getComments(){

 return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response:Response)=> response.json())
        .catch(this._errorHandler);

  }

  _errorHandler(error:Response){
       console.error(error);
     return Observable.throw(error ||"Server Error");

 }

}
```

the above code works great with this url https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts

but does not work with this url http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/driverStandings.json

any ideas ...TIA

Comment: can you post what error  are you getting ? my be you put https instead of http. I tested the second url and it works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aravind is on the right track here, but `MRData` case sensitive, and mapping is a bit off. The correct way to map the response here would be:

```
return this._http.get(this._url)
    .map((response:Response)=> response.json().MRData)
    .catch(this._errorHandler);
}
```

Your component:

```
getData() {
  this.service.getData()
    .subscribe(data => {
      this.data = data;
    });
}
```

Then you can access data, e.g like:

```
<div>
  <b>Series:</b> {{data?.series}}<br>
  <a><b>Url:</b> {{data?.url}}</a>
</div>
```

Then you seem to have a lot of nested objects in your response, so this might help you: [Access / process (nested) objects, arrays or JSON](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11922383/access-process-nested-objects-arrays-or-json)

Here's a demo with mock JSON, but I did try that url you provided and the data was received fine. So replicating the plunker should work fine in your app :)

[**DEMO**](https://plnkr.co/edit/9V00JFePpYYVFtZPfvrS?p=preview)

Comment: Awesome AJT_82 , I will give it a whirl, thanks a lot

Comment: So how did it go? :)

Comment: sorry for the late reply ..How go i drill down to a specific base node for eg "DriverStandings":[{"position":"1",... {"position":"2",.. so on and filter anything above that is it even possible

Comment: got it to work .. finally ... thanks all .. this is the only change i made in the get request  json().MRData.StandingsTable.StandingsLists[0].DriverStandings

Answer (score 0):

To make the second one work you need to get the data using

```
return this._http.get(this._url)
        .map((response:Response)=> response.MRDATA.json())
        .catch(this._errorHandler);

  }
```

Because in this [working one](https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/posts) the data is in array of objects type Meaning

[image]

The one which [does not work](http://ergast.com/api/f1/2016/driverStandings.json) is completely single object

[image]